# How to add a rectangular layout on string in UITextfield with a clear button in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to do something very similar to email address textfield in iOS. Just like email address gets highlighted in a different colour and has a clear button next to it. On clicking the clear button that entire email address should get deleted.Attaching a picture of that. Can you please give me some pointers? I know how to use NSAttributedString to highlight the text but no idea how to add the clear button next to it. Thank you! [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would subclass a UIView object say for example call it emailAddressView with an associated nib file where you add a UILabel for the name and a UIButton for the 'x' button.

You could then add this view as a subview to your UITextfield as the user enters in valid entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. In this case, say for example I remove the first name in the above picture by removing the subview(triggered by clicking the x button), then I have to manually adjust the position of the second button and subsequent ones right?

Comment: Yes you would. That could be done I think the easiest by creating a mutable array of custom objects (like an emailUser object or something along those lines) that contain your data. This mutable array would be a parallel between the various views and their respective data. Then you could create a method which reloads your views in the textfield based on this array, allowing you to just call this method to layout your views each time an addition or deletion is made to them.

Answer (score 0):

add a UIButton as subview of your UITextView

Comment: THanks a lot for the quick response